# SQL : Getting last records for two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have two tables

1. Companies
2. company_payments

each company is doing two types of payments `vat` and  `witholding_tax`, i am doing following query which returns me  company's last  payments for the current year

```
SELECT * FROM companies c 
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) max_id, company_id FROM company_payments ) 
c_max ON (c_max.company_id = c.id) 
JOIN company_payments cp ON (cp.id = c_max.max_id)
WHERE 
YEAR(cp.last_payment) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Below is the structure of my `company_payments` table

[image]

Now instead of returning one last payment i want to return last payment for payment type 'vat' and 'witholding_tax' both , if its not there would need an empty record ,

Could someone please advise me how can i achieve this

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output in text format. And describe, what do you mean by *both*, because they are different rows in your table and there's no any relationship between two different rows in table (I mean you cannot tell which `vat` is for which `witholding_tax`)

Comment: sure, Each company will have two payment types vat and witholdingtax, i want last entry of vat payment and withholding_tax payment for the current year against the company id , i hope its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select cp.*
from company_payments cp
where cp.last_payment = (select max(cp2.last_payment)
                         from company_payments cp2
                         where cp2.company_id = cp.company_id and
                               cp2.payment_type = cp.payment_type
                        );
```

If you want to filter only on the most recent year, you can add the date filter to the outer query.